# How are variables as recursion method parameters processed?

Tags: java, recursion

I want to numerate all elements on my xhtml page. I expect every next element put into HashMap with bigger order.

> private void addComponents(HashMap infos,
>             List components, Integer order, FacesContext context){
>
> ```
>   System.out.println("Start: "+order);
>
>   if ((components == null) || components.isEmpty())
>   {
>       System.out.println("return: "+order);
>       return;
>   }
>   order = order + 1000;
>   for (UIComponent c : components) {
>       System.out.println("HashMap: "+order);
>       infos.put(c.getClientId(context), order);
>       addComponents(infos, c.getChildren(), order, context);
>       System.out.println("Out: "+order);
>       order = order + 1000;
>   }
>   System.out.println("End: "+order);
>   return;
> ```
>
> }

I have as **output** and wrong numeration

```
HashMap: 1000

Start: 1000

return: 1000

Out: 1000

HashMap: 2000

Start: 2000

return: 2000

Out: 2000

HashMap: 3000

Start: 3000

HashMap: 4000

Start: 4000

return: 4000

Out: 4000

HashMap: 5000

Start: 5000

return: 5000
Out: 5000
HashMap: 6000

Start: 6000

return: 6000

Out: 6000

End: 7000

Out: 3000

HashMap: 4000
```

at the same the following method works nice

> private int addComponents(HashMap infos,
>             List components, Integer order, FacesContext context
>             ) {
>         if ((components == null) || components.isEmpty())
>             return order;
>
> ```
>   for (UIComponent c : components) {
>
>           order = order + 1000;
>           infos.put(c.getClientId(context), order);
>
>       order = addComponents(infos, c.getChildren(), order, context);
>
>   }
>   return order;
> ```
>
> }

Why do those two methods work differently?

Answer (score 2):

You must remember that parameter assignment in Java does not affect that calling method. SO when you do `order = order + 1000` this does not affect the value of `order` in the calling instance of `addComponents`. By returning the value you allow the caller to update it's value to that of the recursively called one.

One option to solve this would be to use a field but then you might run into thread-safety issues if you are multi-threaded.

Comment: The order value is being passed on every recursion as addComponents(infos, c.getChildren(), **order**, context). So, wouldn't it reflect in the called method as well?

Comment: The CALLED instance of the method gets the value that is passed in. But if the CALLED instance updates the parameter's value the CALLING instance does not see this update.

Answer (score 0):

The second method works fine because the order value passed recursively has already been incremented and hence it reflects within the recursion as well.

In your first method you pass the order value as is (without incrementing first), which passes the value to the next recursion as is; and continuing in the same fashion till you hit the bottom of the recursion the order value remains at 1000 and the same is populated in your map `infos`.

It's only when the stack unwinds that the order value gets incremented but the value that you placed in `infos` map still remains the same 1000 although the `println()` statements might make you think otherwise.